# Can I put a 75 watt equivalent led bulb in a fixture that says 60 watts max?

Tags: electrical

Can I put a 75 watt equivalent led bulb(1100 lumes). In a fixture that says 60 watts max. I know the power going to the bulb is way less and the heat is also way less so should I worry about it? I'm trying to get more light out of a two bulb fixture with a 60 watt bulb max by putting 75 watt led's in it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10148/can-i-use-a-23-w-cfl-in-a-fixture-thats-rated-for-a-60-w-incandescent

Comment: I guess the question is *has the world of equivalents changed in this area since 2011*?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can.  If you could find it, you could put 60 W (actual) LEDs in it, which would be equivalent to like 750 W incandescent.  The maximum stickers are for heat dissipation as well as electrical wiring capacity.

The only real concern is whether the dimability of the LEDs match the light switch or controller.

Answer (score -1):

For a 1100 lumens 75W light, you can use a 12W LED light to replace it directly.  Now 12W can reach 1200 lumens, so more lights and energy saving.