# Why won't a LED bulb work in a standard light fixture?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, cfl

I have a wall fixture in my Brooklyn apartment's bathroom that is my only source of light. A sticker on the fixture says that it is Max 75W. The other day, the 14W / 60W equivalent CFL that was in it since I moved in burned out and I had to replace it. Since it is my only source of light in the room and it is 2015, I bought a 13W / 75W equivalent LED bulb to go in it, the highest I could find at the local hardware store. No problem, right? A 13W bulb is way lower than 75W.**

The strangest thing is, when I screwed in the new bulb, the light refused to work. When I screwed in a larger CFL, say a 20W / 75W equivalent, it also refused to work. Only when I screwed in another 14W / 60W equivalent CFL did it finally work. All brand new bulbs that work in other sockets around the apartment.

Does anyone know what might be behind this? Should I get an electrician in to check this out, or are some light fixtures just not compatible with LEDs?

** Ref: [Can I put a 75 watt equivalent led bulb in a fixture that says 60 watts max?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/38811/can-i-put-a-75-watt-equivalent-led-bulb-in-a-fixture-that-says-60-watts-max)

Comment: Any dimmers or maybe a timer that operates the light?  Also some LED/CF lights have a start up time (sometimes up to two seconds) which has can make us think that a light is not working.  2 seconds is an eternity when we are used to instant.

Comment: @diceless No dimmers. The "start up" time is a good point. I will try that and write back. However, the same LED in another lamp elsewhere in the apartment turned on instantly.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of, ballast/transformer section of the bulb might be too big for the fixture preventing it from making a good contact in the socket.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found the answer! [diceless](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/11931/diceless) set me on the right track in looking at where the foot of the bulb is connecting to the fixture.

Since it was an older fixture (installed in the 80's, I think), the hot contact (Number 1 in [this diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/3Way_Socket_Contacts.jpg) ) was bent down, and it was connecting with the smaller bulb but not the bigger LED bulb.

With the circuit turned off at the breaker I reached in with a wooden tongue depressor and bent it upwards slightly. Then, I made sure to screw the LED bulb in tightly. Flicking the switch it was bright as day!

Comment: Did you mean to say "Number 1" or "Number 2" instead of "Number 3"?  Number three should not be hot; it should be neutral and I don't see how you could adjust it with a tongue depressor.

Comment: @Paul Yes, #1. Corrected.

Comment: I had the same issue with a lamp that had three bulbs; my LED bulbs would work in two, but not in the third (I could get CFL and incandescent bulbs to work, however).  This solution worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This has worked for me on more than one occasion.  For some reason, LED bulbs tend to have slightly less depth -- but they are likely to work if you bend up the contact in the base of the socket.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with LED bulbs not working in a socket that an incandescent bulb worked. After making sure that the the circuit breaker was off, or the lamp was unplugged, I inserted a pair of thin pliers into the socket and pulled the bottom contact a little.  After that, an LED bulb worked fine.